# get the distinct value of a column which each cell has multiple value R

Tags: r, dataframe

my data is look like this :

```
id  book_id                     numberofbook_id
 1     ["19167120","237494310","195166798"]    3      
 2     ["19167120","237494310"]                2       
 3     []                                      0
```

what I am trying to do is first to have a diffrent datafrane which has diffrent book_id as single

```
 book_id
 "19167120"
 "237494310"
 "195166798"
```

and then based on this , group the id

```
 book_id       id      numberofid
 "19167120"    [1,2]       2
 "237494310"   [1,2]       2
 "195166798"   [1]         1
```

Ps :I was thinking of first combine all the cell in to one by `unlist` and then use `unique` function to get the unique one and then put them into a column.but `unlist` wasn't the answer in here.

Comment: i think you need to use `reshape` package.

Comment: @AvinashRaj , thanks for your comment, I saw the package but I have the problem of what formula should I use in order to get this.

Comment: You can use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package, and then aggregate the results using "data.table".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer, starting with "df1" as defined below, you can try the following:

```
library(splitstackshape)
Temp <- cSplit(as.data.table(df1)[, book_id := gsub("[][]", "", book_id)],
               "book_id", ",", "long")
Temp <- na.omit(Temp, by = "book_id_new")
#    id numberofbook_id book_id_new
# 1:  1               3  "19167120"
# 2:  1               3 "237494310"
# 3:  1               3 "195166798"
# 4:  2               2  "19167120"
# 5:  2               2 "237494310"
```

In the step above:

- The `gsub` step just removes the `[` and the `]` from the "book_id" column.
- `cSplit` splits the data into a long form.
- `na.omit` drops the resulting unnecessary `NA` values.

With the data in that form, you can now easily "aggregate" your data as you wish. Since the result of "Temp" is a `data.table`, you can just go ahead with the "data.table" package.

```
Temp[, list(ID = paste(id, collapse = ","), 
            numofid = length(id)), by = "book_id_new"]
#    book_id_new  ID numofid
# 1:  "19167120" 1,2       2
# 2: "237494310" 1,2       2
# 3: "195166798"   1       1
```

---

Sample data:

```
 df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, 
                       book_id = c("[\"19167120\", \"237494310 \",\"195166798\"]", 
                                   "[\"19167120\",\"237494310\"]", "[]"),
                       numberofbook_id = c(3L, 2L, 0L)), 
                       .Names = c("id", "book_id", "numberofbook_id"), 
                       class = "data.frame", 
                       row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ananda Mahto, that help alot, but there is just one thing , when run the code it give me this error  `object 'book_id_new' not found `which I don't know why and instead I use the book_id.

Comment: I am really sorry to brought this up but I'm having a problem with my own data,in the Id section there are some 000 as ids which there is not any 000 id in that in original data, and also when I check the id in temp after getting new book id , there wasn't any 000 id in there as well, I can't figure out what the problem is, could help me in this ?

Comment: @academic.user, hard to say -- can you narrow down the sample data to recreate a similar behavior?

Comment: thanks you @Ananda Mahto, after narrowing the sample I find out that there was no problem with the `paste` or `length`, there is a problem with write.csv, it changed all the data,as it is not relevant to the question I create a new one [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539091/write-csv-changes-the-data-in-r)