# write.csv changes the data in R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to use `write.csv` but it give me wrong answer,what am I doing wrong, what should I do to preserve that ?

sample data :

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(10,5788,6877,35814,10,3637,3751,21106,21144,21409,24765,
                       34988,6,904,2014,26509,2924,34034,35927)                     
                  , book_id = c("1427542124131848","1427542124131848","1427542124131848","1427542124131848",
                                "677165348994231","677165348994231","677165348994231","677165348994231",
                                "677165348994231","677165348994231","677165348994231","677165348994231",
                                "74117771667","74117771667","74117771667","74117771667","74117771667","74117771667","74117771667"),
                   class = "data.frame")
```

code :

```
Temp=as.data.table(df1)
t2=Temp[, list(ID = paste(id, collapse = ","), 
           numofid = length(id)), by = "book_id"]

 #        book_id                                         ID numofid
#1 1427542124131848                         10,5788,6877,35814       4
#2  677165348994231 10,3637,3751,21106,21144,21409,24765,34988       8
#3      74117771667          6,904,2014,26509,2924,34034,35927       7

write.csv(t2  , file = "t2.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

csv file :

```
 #1.42754E+15   105,788,687,735,814 4
 #6.77165E+14   10,363,737,512,110,600,000,000,000,000,000,000  8
 #74117771667   690,420,142,650,929,000,000,000,000 7
```

Comment: Did you extract the csv number from Excel?

Comment: @KFB , yeah,thanks for the hint and I double check and yeah that is the problem.but why dose this happen , and how to preserve that ?

Comment: Your `dput` seems to be invalid. But, recreating your data, I don't have the problem you are describing here.

Comment: From what you show here, it seems like Excel is interpreting the "ID" column as a really big number and inserting thousands separators. Does R read the CSV correctly?

Comment: thanks Ananda Mahto for your comment,when i read the file , ID part is correct and the book_id part is in scientific format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you opened the csv file in Excel and Excel displayed in scientific notation.  And as @Ananda opined, Excel could be reading the big number differently. May be you could try `write.table` function:

```
# the t2.txt file will be saved to your R working directory
write.table(t2, sep="\t", file="t2.txt", row.names=FALSE)
```

Excel is notorious for not being able to get numbers right. One article to share: [Excel spreadsheets are hard to get right](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2014/11/excel-spreadsheets-are-hard-to-get-right/)

Comment: thanks for you help @KFB, my main problem is with ID column and I couldn't see them rightly at all.

Comment: thanks @KFB, so apparently I couldn't work with excel.